# Multiple R=301 redirect rules in .htaccess, single redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say there are two rewrite rules I'd like to inform the browser about:

- removing www prefix (`http://www.example.org` to `http://example.org`)
- removing index.php (`http://example.org/index.php` to `http://example.org`)

I'd like to apply both rules, and I'd like either rule to result in a 301 redirect. If both rules match, I'd like there to be only a single 301 redirect.

The problem is, when a rule has an `[R]` flag, I must also specify an `[L]` (last) flag to go with it according to the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r).

> You will almost always want to use [R] in conjunction with [L] (that is, use [R,L]) because on its own, the [R] flag prepends http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in request' warnings.

Are there any workarounds so that I can have both rules not result in 2 redirects?

```
RewriteEngine On

# Naked domains
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, L flag is to tell the rewriting process to stop processing new rewrites that may follow these ones, but since you are doing a external redirect I doubt not having it would cause issues. Still, the real point is why you use mod_rewrite (or .htaccess) for your case being it that simple (mod_rewrite should be left for when there is no simpler option).

This is the correct way (without mod_rewrite).

```
#NameVirtualhost *:80 <- add and uncomment this only if your version is 2.2

<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName example.org
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/htdocs
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/(.*) /$1

    #other config
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.org
    Redirect 301 / http://example.org/
</Virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.* - [E=A:http://%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php - [E=B:/]

RewriteCond %{ENV:A} .+
RewriteCond %{ENV:B} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=B:/$1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:A} .+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:B} .+
RewriteRule .* %{ENV:A}%{ENV:B} [R=301,L]
```